# Encode quoted-printable email in R

Tags: r, email, encoding

Is there package or function for encode quoted-printable text from email using R?

For example

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="windows-1251"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=CA=EE=EB=EB=E5=E3=E8!
```

How can I get string ="Коллеги!" in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Encoding` from the `base` package should do the job. For example:

```
x <- "fa\xE7ile"
Encoding(x)
Encoding(x) <- "latin1"
x
```

would return:

```
[1] "façile"
```

Your *text from email* would be simply a string vector so you can encode it as you please.

Comment: It s works! Thanks. May be you know how i can replace "=" on "\x"? When i tried x=gsub(pattern = "=",replacement = '\x',x =  "=C2=EB=E0=E4=E8=EC=E8=F0,") , i got "Error: '\x' used without hex digits in character string starting "'\x"" .

Comment: It may be good to browse Stacks for smiliar questions and if there is nothing that answers your question you can ask new one. If I understand correctly, which I'm not sure, if you want to replace `=` with `x` you would simply do: `x = gsub(pattern = "=",replacement = 'x',x = "=C2=EB=E0=E4=E8=EC=E8=F0,")` but I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: just add one more slash to gsub, like this: gsub(pattern = "=",replacement = '\\x',x = "=C2=EB=E0=E4=E8=EC=E8=F0,")

Comment: This does not seem to work for the example provided in the question. 
`x <- "=CA=EE=EB=EB=E5=E3=E8!";Encoding(x) <- "latin1";x`
gives `[1] "=CA=EE=EB=EB=E5=E3=E8!"`