# Decoding quoted-printable string in R

Tags: r, decoding, quoted-printable

I have extracted displayed sender names from .mbox file exported by Gmail and read in with tm.plugin.mail. Some names are in ["quoted-printable"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.7) format (e.g. =?UTF-8?Q?stern=2Ede_-_t=C3=A4glich?=), including both special characters and something that looks like a specification of the encoding (=?UTF-8?).
I want to convert these to a UTF-8 or latin1 encoded character vector.

I have tried `Encoding()` and `iconv()` that I would use for other encoding issues without success:

```
qp_encoded <- "=?UTF-8?Q?stern=2Ede_-_t=C3=A4glich?="

# List of available encodings
iconvlist()
# On my computer (OS X) there seems to be no encoding related to MIME
# or quoted-printable
# None of them give correct result
for(encoding in iconvlist()){
print(iconv(qp_encoded, from = encoding, to = "UTF-8"))
}

# Accepted answer on other post (see below)
Encoding(qp_encoded)
Encoding(qp_encoded) <- "latin1"
qp_encoded # No change in encoding
```

There is one answer to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044432/encode-quoted-printable-email-in-r), but the answer is just an example copied from `Encoding()` and doesn't work with the op's example.
There are several other questions relating to the issue in Go and C and a function [in PHP](http://php.net/manual/de/function.iconv-mime-decode.php) and [javascript](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/quoted-printable), but I can't figure out how to call them from or export them to R.

EDIT: I now use Python and `quopri.decodestring()` via the rPython package, but the solution doesn't seem very efficient.

```
library("rPython")
python.assign( "stringVector", qp_encoded)
 python.exec(c(
   "import quopri",
   "result = []",
   "for i in range(0, len(stringVector)):",
   "\tresult.append(str(quopri.decodestring(stringVector[i], header=False)))"
 ))
test <- python.get("result")
```

Is there any other R function/package that converts quoted-printable? Can I extend `iconv()` to also convert quoted-printable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been thinking of making a pkg for quoted printable encoding/decoding. This is a pretty fast lookup-table version:

```
qp_before <- c("=00", "=01", "=02", "=03", "=04", "=05", "=06", "=07", "=08", "=09", "=0A",
               "=0B", "=0C", "=0D", "=0E", "=0F", "=10", "=11", "=12", "=13", "=14", "=15",
               "=16", "=17", "=18", "=19", "=1A", "=1B", "=1C", "=1D", "=1E", "=1F", "=20",
               "=21", "=22", "=23", "=24", "=25", "=26", "=27", "=28", "=29", "=2A", "=2B",
               "=2C", "=2D", "=2E", "=2F", "=30", "=31", "=32", "=33", "=34", "=35", "=36",
               "=37", "=38", "=39", "=3A", "=3B", "=3C", "=3D", "=3E", "=3F", "=40", "=41",
               "=42", "=43", "=44", "=45", "=46", "=47", "=48", "=49", "=4A", "=4B", "=4C",
               "=4D", "=4E", "=4F", "=50", "=51", "=52", "=53", "=54", "=55", "=56", "=57",
               "=58", "=59", "=5A", "=5B", "=5C", "=5D", "=5E", "=5F", "=60", "=61", "=62", 
               "=63", "=64", "=65", "=66", "=67", "=68", "=69", "=6A", "=6B", "=6C", "=6D", 
               "=6E", "=6F", "=70", "=71", "=72", "=73", "=74", "=75", "=76", "=77", "=78",
               "=79", "=7A", "=7B", "=7C", "=7D", "=7E", "=7F", "=80", "=81", "=82", "=83", 
               "=84", "=85", "=86", "=87", "=88", "=89", "=8A", "=8B", "=8C", "=8D", "=8E", 
               "=8F", "=90", "=91", "=92", "=93", "=94", "=95", "=96", "=97", "=98", "=99", 
               "=9A", "=9B", "=9C", "=9D", "=9E", "=9F", "=A0", "=A1", "=A2", "=A3", "=A4", 
               "=A5", "=A6", "=A7", "=A8", "=A9", "=AA", "=AB", "=AC", "=AD", "=AE", "=AF",
               "=B0", "=B1", "=B2", "=B3", "=B4", "=B5", "=B6", "=B7", "=B8", "=B9", "=BA", 
               "=BB", "=BC", "=BD", "=BE", "=BF", "=C0", "=C1", "=C2", "=C3", "=C4", "=C5",
               "=C6", "=C7", "=C8", "=C9", "=CA", "=CB", "=CC", "=CD", "=CE", "=CF", "=D0",
               "=D1", "=D2", "=D3", "=D4", "=D5", "=D6", "=D7", "=D8", "=D9", "=DA", "=DB", 
               "=DC", "=DD", "=DE", "=DF", "=E0", "=E1", "=E2", "=E3", "=E4", "=E5", "=E6", 
               "=E7", "=E8", "=E9", "=EA", "=EB", "=EC", "=ED", "=EE", "=EF", "=F0", "=F1", 
               "=F2", "=F3", "=F4", "=F5", "=F6", "=F7", "=F8", "=F9", "=FA", "=FB", "=FC", 
               "=FD", "=FE", "=FF", "=\r\n")

qp_after <- c("", "\001", "\002", "\003", "\004", "\005", "\006", "\a", "\b", "\t", "\n", 
              "\v", "\f", "\r", "\016", "\017", "\020", "\021", "\022", "\023", "\024", 
              "\025", "\026", "\027", "\030", "\031", "\032", "\033", "\034", "\035", 
              "\036", "\037", " ", "!", "\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+",
              ",", "-", ".", "/", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ":", 
              ";", "<", "=", ">", "?", "@", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", 
              "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", 
              "Y", "Z", "[", "\\", "]", "^", "_", "`", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g",
              "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", 
              "w", "x", "y", "z", "{", "|", "}", "~", "\177", "\x80", "\x81", "\x82", 
              "\x83", "\x84", "\x85", "\x86", "\x87", "\x88", "\x89", "\x8a", "\x8b", 
              "\x8c", "\x8d", "\x8e", "\x8f", "\x90", "\x91", "\x92", "\x93", "\x94", 
              "\x95", "\x96", "\x97", "\x98", "\x99", "\x9a", "\x9b", "\x9c", "\x9d", 
              "\x9e", "\x9f", "\xa0", "\xa1", "\xa2", "\xa3", "\xa4", "\xa5", "\xa6", 
              "\xa7", "\xa8", "\xa9", "\xaa", "\xab", "\xac", "\xad", "\xae", "\xaf", 
              "\xb0", "\xb1", "\xb2", "\xb3", "\xb4", "\xb5", "\xb6", "\xb7", "\xb8", 
              "\xb9", "\xba", "\xbb", "\xbc", "\xbd", "\xbe", "\xbf", "\xc0", "\xc1", 
              "\xc2", "\xc3", "\xc4", "\xc5", "\xc6", "\xc7", "\xc8", "\xc9", "\xca", 
              "\xcb", "\xcc", "\xcd", "\xce", "\xcf", "\xd0", "\xd1", "\xd2", "\xd3", 
              "\xd4", "\xd5", "\xd6", "\xd7", "\xd8", "\xd9", "\xda", "\xdb", "\xdc", 
              "\xdd", "\xde", "\xdf", "\xe0", "\xe1", "\xe2", "\xe3", "\xe4", "\xe5", 
              "\xe6", "\xe7", "\xe8", "\xe9", "\xea", "\xeb", "\xec", "\xed", "\xee", 
              "\xef", "\xf0", "\xf1", "\xf2", "\xf3", "\xf4", "\xf5", "\xf6", "\xf7", 
              "\xf8", "\xf9", "\xfa", "\xfb", "\xfc", "\xfd", "\xfe", "\xff", "")
```

Now to decode:

```
qp_encoded <- "=?UTF-8?Q?stern=2Ede_-_t=C3=A4glich?="

stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(qp_encoded, qp_before, qp_after, vectorize_all=FALSE)

## "=?UTF-8?Q?stern.de_-_täglich?="
```

For now, i've stuck this decoder in my personal R pkg (not on CRAN):

```
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/hrbrmisc")

hrbrmisc::qp_decode(qp_encoded)
```

Comment: The part at the beginning =?UTF-8?Q? and end ?= seems to be part of the MIME encoding for email headers. So far, I remove it with regular expressions. 
Am I correct in assuming that this specifies the encoding for the string in between? I am concerned about robustness in case this is not UTF-8

Comment: that's a separate issue from quoted printable encodings. You can reference page 6 of [RFC 1342](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1342) to see how to handle that specification (it is a hack-ish way to enable specify text encodings in a header).

Comment: A slightly more complete implementation including encoding is now available in `{emayili}` (from version 0.6.2): `emayili::qp_encode()` and `emayili::qp_decode()`.